# problem to submit data in firebase for second form in navigation bar first form work fine. Actual isse is to link another activity in Mainactivity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-fragmentactivity

**Hi there, I've used inbuilt navigation bar MainActivity and three fragments of home gallery and slideshow. In which I have two forms one is in home fragment and another is in gallery fragment. Home form is working fine whereas gallery form not. Both form fields are exactly the same except the database name. I was submitting both form data by on click function in MainActivity but for gallery form. it got crashed as there is an error of submit button object of gallery form is null as its landing page is home so there is only one submit button. then, I created one more activity extending mainactivity in it. Now crash issue is resolved but still, it doesn't write to database.**

*MainActivity working fine*

```
@Override
    protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onInstance");
//        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        //Checkbox of Guide
        english = findViewById(R.id.eng_box);
        interview = findViewById(R.id.inter_box);
        internship = findViewById(R.id.intern_box);
        resume = findViewById(R.id.cv_box);
        promotion = findViewById(R.id.job_box);
        confidence = findViewById(R.id.cnfdc_box);
        exams = findViewById(R.id.exam_box);
        //make button object
        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.sendButton);




        // Write a message to the database
        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        final String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
        final String uemail = firebaseUser.getEmail();
        assert firebaseUser != null;
        final String una = firebaseUser.getDisplayName(); //display the entire name
        assert una != null;
        final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("Expert_expertise").child(uid);
        final DatabaseReference TRef = database.getReference().child("Trainee_req").child(uid);
//        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
//        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Expert Expertise");
//        myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.child(uid).getValue(String.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });



        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myRef.child("Name").setValue(una);
                myRef.child("Email").setValue(uemail);
                if(english.isChecked()) {
                    myRef.child("Spoken English").setValue("True");
                }
                else{
                    myRef.child("Spoken English").setValue("False");
                }

                if(interview.isChecked()) {
                    myRef.child("Interview Tips").setValue("True");
                }
                else{
                    myRef.child("Interview Tips").setValue("False");
                }
                if(internship.isChecked()) {
                    myRef.child("Internship Guide").setValue("True");
                }

                else{
                    myRef.child("Internship Guide").setValue("False");
                }
                if(resume.isChecked()) {
                    myRef.child("Resume Building").setValue("True");
                }
                else{
                    myRef.child("Resume Building").setValue("False");
                }
                if(promotion.isChecked()) {
                    myRef.child("Job Promotion").setValue("True");
                }
                else{
                    myRef.child("Job Promotion").setValue("False");
                }
                if(confidence.isChecked()) {
                    myRef.child("Confidence Development").setValue("True");
                }
                else{
                    myRef.child("Confidence Development").setValue("False");
                }
                if(exams.isChecked()) {
                    myRef.child("Competitive Exams").setValue("True");
                }
                else{
                    myRef.child("Competitive Exams").setValue("False");
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Thank You! Your expertise is successfully saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
//        System.out.print("Hello, Saurabh");
//        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unable to submit",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        Log.i(TAG, "Hello Saurabh");
    }
```

*GalleryForm*

```
package com.example.pdshell;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.annotations.Nullable;

public class GalleryForm extends Dashboard {

    private static final String TAG="Mymessage";
    CheckBox t_english,t_interview,t_internship,t_resume,t_promotion,t_confidence,t_exams;
    Button sendButton, t_button;
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_gallery);

        //Checkbox of Trainee
        t_english = findViewById(R.id.t_eng_box);
        t_interview = findViewById(R.id.t_inter_box);
        t_internship = findViewById(R.id.t_intern_box);
        t_resume = findViewById(R.id.t_cv_box);
        t_promotion = findViewById(R.id.t_job_box);
        t_confidence = findViewById(R.id.t_cnfdc_box);
        t_exams = findViewById(R.id.t_exam_box);
        //make button object
        t_button = findViewById(R.id.t_sendButton);

        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        final String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
        final String uemail = firebaseUser.getEmail();
        assert firebaseUser != null;
        final String una = firebaseUser.getDisplayName(); //display the entire name
        assert una != null;
        final DatabaseReference TRef = database.getReference().child("Trainee_req").child(uid);

        TRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.child(uid).getValue(String.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });

        System.out.print("Hello, Saurabh@");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unable to submit!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "Hello Saurabh#");

        t_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TRef.child("Name").setValue(una);
                TRef.child("Email").setValue(uemail);
                if (t_english.isChecked()) {
                    TRef.child("Spoken English").setValue("True");
                } else {
                    TRef.child("Spoken English").setValue("False");
                }
                System.out.print("Hello, Saurabh$");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unable to submit%",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i(TAG, "Hello Saurabh^");

                if (t_interview.isChecked()) {
                    TRef.child("Interview Tips").setValue("True");
                } else {
                    TRef.child("Interview Tips").setValue("False");
                }
                if (t_internship.isChecked()) {
                    TRef.child("Internship Guide").setValue("True");
                } else {
                    TRef.child("Internship Guide").setValue("False");
                }
                if (t_resume.isChecked()) {
                    TRef.child("Resume Building").setValue("True");
                } else {
                    TRef.child("Resume Building").setValue("False");
                }
                if (t_promotion.isChecked()) {
                    TRef.child("Job Promotion").setValue("True");
                } else {
                    TRef.child("Job Promotion").setValue("False");
                }
                if (t_confidence.isChecked()) {
                    TRef.child("Confidence Development").setValue("True");
                } else {
                    TRef.child("Confidence Development").setValue("False");
                }
                if (t_exams.isChecked()) {
                    TRef.child("Competitive Exams").setValue("True");
                } else {
                    TRef.child("Competitive Exams").setValue("False");
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank you! Your requirements is successfully saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**logcat**

```
020-04-25 20:38:00.748 21631-18049/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting period=86400000 target_class=com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayReceiver required_network_type=0 runtime=1587827280741 required_idleness_state=0 extras={"com.firebase.jobdispatcher.tag":{"retry_all":4},"com.firebase.jobdispatcher.trigger_type":{"1":0},"com.firebase.jobdispatcher.replace_current":{"true":3},"com.firebase.jobdispatcher.persistent":{"2":0},"com.firebase.jobdispatcher.maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"com.firebase.jobdispatcher.initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"com.firebase.jobdispatcher.retry_policy":{"1":0},"com.firebase.jobdispatcher.window_end":{"86400":0},"com.firebase.jobdispatcher.service":{"com.phonepe.phonepecore.gcm.FailedRequestReattemptHelper":4},"com.firebase.jobdispatcher.recurring":{"false":3},"com.firebase.jobdispatcher.constraints":{"2":0},"com.firebase.jobdispatcher.window_start":{"1":0}} source=8 service_kind=0 target_package=com.phonepe.app source_version=1 last_runtime=0 user_id=0 job_id=-1 requires_charging=0 tag=retry_all flex_time=1000 task_type=0 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}}
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:831)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1433)
        at aqch.a(:com.google.android.gms@201216030@20.12.16 (100408-306753009):78)
        at aqbw.a(:com.google.android.gms@201216030@20.12.16 (100408-306753009):167)
        at aqbw.a(:com.google.android.gms@201216030@20.12.16 (100408-306753009):21)
        at aqbw.a(:com.google.android.gms@201216030@20.12.16 (100408-306753009):161)
        at apyg.run(:com.google.android.gms@201216030@20.12.16 (100408-306753009):8)
        at thp.b(:com.google.android.gms@201216030@20.12.16 (100408-306753009):12)
        at thp.run(:com.google.android.gms@201216030@20.12.16 (100408-306753009):7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at tno.run(:com.google.android.gms@201216030@20.12.16 (100408-306753009):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2020-04-25 20:38:01.674 2456-2456/? I/NetLowlatency: setDataPhoneId: 1
2020-04-25 20:38:01.686 2456-2456/? I/NetLowlatency: setDataPhoneId: 1
2020-04-25 20:38:01.686 2456-2456/? I/NetLowlatency: is automode : true
2020-04-25 20:38:01.686 2456-2456/? I/NetLowlatency: get the current uplink latency level is 1
2020-04-25 20:38:01.850 13692-13692/? I/hostapd: wlan0: STA 4c:18:9a:b9:4f:2a IEEE 802.11: associated
2020-04-25 20:38:01.850 844-844/? I/wificond: New station 4c:18:9a:b9:4f:2a associated with hotspot
2020-04-25 20:38:01.850 13692-13692/? I/hostapd: wlan0: STA 4c:18:9a:b9:4f:2a IEEE 802.11: associated
2020-04-25 20:38:01.850 13692-13692/? E/hostapd:   New STA hapd->num_sta=1 hapd->conf->max_num_sta=255 net.wifi.vivosoftap.maxsta=1
2020-04-25 20:38:01.850 13692-13692/? E/hostapd: no more room for new STAs (1/255)
```

Comment: Can you share the logcat?

Comment: As mentioned It is working now just submit button of gallery form is not submitting data. Also home form is submitting data so there is no problem with realtime db connection.

Comment: logcat updated. suggest a way to change mainactivity to gallery form activity. using item of navigation bar having id nav_home and nav_gallery in layout file.